# Cannot configure "plugins" or add elements in taskbar (application launcher, XLDE?)

Tags: desktop

Back to Linux after 20 years away from it, please pardon my rusty ignorance :-)

I've just installed my Raspberry Pi5 (default OS) and need to add some apps to the "launcher" (between the Raspberry button and the open windows. Not the full menu", the apps bar itself.

I've done some extensive reading, many sources tell me to:
Right click on panel.
Click on [Add/Remove Panel Items].
Open the [Panel Applets] tab.
Click on [Preferences].
Locate your new item in the menu and click on it.

Problem is, I never get the [Add/Remove Panel Items].
I have a "Add/Remove plugins" that shows me the launcher being on the left side of the bar, but clicking on "Configure" only allows me to change the icon spacing.

I've also looked for the "*.desktop" files under /usr/share/applications/ but I suspect this is linked to desktop apps only.

Can you please guide me to add and remove some apps to that menu bar? For example, I'd like to be able to remove the default terminal and add Xfce terminal instead. I managed to have it on my desktop, but never on the menu bar.

Thank you so much!

Comment: The RpiOS desktop is a modded version of LXDE, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Add/Remove Plugins]** is the menu on Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm.
Select one of the Available plugins in the right hand column.

Configure is there to modify the selected plugin.

To add items to the Launcher select the appropriate item in the Menu, right click and select **Add to Launcher**
There is also a remove option but that can be done by right clicking on e.g. *Terminal* and select **Remove from Launcher**

---

You may not see an immediate change to Launcher. A reboot/restart may be required.

Comment: Thank you so much!
So to easily add an entry to the launcher, I need to right-click on a menu shortcut.
Appreciate the help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I was the same as you several years back. This may not be the correct way to do it, but it works for me. If `$HOME/.config/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/panels/panel` does not exist, copy `/etc/xdg/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/panels/panel` to above. In your $HOME/.config/.../panel file change (vi or nano) the third `Plugin{` `type=launchbar` third Button down `id=lxterminal.desktop` change to your Xfce terminal desktop. `Excute lxpanelctl restart`.